# Time Capsule giving high ping times for wireless

Tags: ping, wifi, backup

We've just set up an Apple Time Capsule for our network, and while things run fine in wired mode, with wireless mode ping time fluctuates wildly from 0.5 to 400ms:

Ping from a Macbook Pro to 10.0.111.1, which is the time capsule machine itself (DHCP server and gateway)

Wired:

```
64 bytes from 10.0.111.1: icmp_seq=1457 ttl=255 time=0.229 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.111.1: icmp_seq=1458 ttl=255 time=0.357 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.111.1: icmp_seq=1459 ttl=255 time=0.311 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.111.1: icmp_seq=1460 ttl=255 time=0.330 ms
```

Wireless (2.4GHz and 5GHz give similar results):

```
64 bytes from 10.0.111.1: icmp_seq=1681 ttl=255 time=0.681 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.111.1: icmp_seq=1682 ttl=255 time=84.105 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.111.1: icmp_seq=1683 ttl=255 time=5.639 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.111.1: icmp_seq=1684 ttl=255 time=234.416 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.111.1: icmp_seq=1685 ttl=255 time=156.089 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.111.1: icmp_seq=1686 ttl=255 time=77.471 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.111.1: icmp_seq=1687 ttl=255 time=0.636 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.111.1: icmp_seq=1688 ttl=255 time=0.728 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.111.1: icmp_seq=1689 ttl=255 time=0.742 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.111.1: icmp_seq=1690 ttl=255 time=70.863 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.111.1: icmp_seq=1691 ttl=255 time=298.970 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.111.1: icmp_seq=1692 ttl=255 time=220.510 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.111.1: icmp_seq=1693 ttl=255 time=0.687 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.111.1: icmp_seq=1694 ttl=255 time=377.065 ms
```

I've tried switching between 2.4GHz and 5GHz (set a different name for each to be sure I'm on the right one), changing to every channel on both, and it makes no difference whatsoever in the ping behavior. There are 6 other reachable WIFI access points in this area so it seems unlikely that it's crosstalk.

Is there anything else I can do to diagnose this issue?